# Web.Config - URL rewrite to WWW, HTTPS and Primary Domain - URL Chain Problems?

Tags: asp.net, https, url-rewriting, redirect

Pretty new to this, but trying hard to understand.

I was able to redirect non-www to www, and http to https, but now I need to redirect a domain pointer to the primary. i.e. Domain2.com to Domain1.com.  I am concerned about the URL chain and taking a hit on SEO.  Should I put the domain redirect before the WWW\https one?

```
<rule name="Force WWW and SSL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^www]" />
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain1.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>

<!-- Just add this?  Should it go in front of the other? -->
<rule name ="Redirect Domain2 to Domain1" enabled="true">
  <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domain2.com" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https//www.domain1.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead two rules you can create one rule with multiple conditions:

```
<rule name="All in one rule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.domain1\.com$" negate="true" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain1.com{URL}" />
</rule>
```

This rule will do the following:

- Redirect all other domains (domain1.com, domain2.com and etc) to `www.domain1.com`
- Redirect HTTP to HTTPS

This rule will make only one necessary redirect instead of multiple redirects as your current rules

Comment: it took me a little bit to figure out what you are doing Mr. Victor.  I am gonna simplify it into my own terms.  1.  If its not https>>redirect to primary domain with Https. 2. If the base URL does not match perfectly, redirect to the primary domain with Https.  Excellent!  Thank you sir!

Comment: <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain1.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />  I am not sure what the {URL} parameter does on yours.

Comment: `appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent"` is not really necessary, because this values is default values.